# Show Bootstrap popover by dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning how to use Bootstrap and would like to know how to dynamic show a popover against an input field within a form.  I have tried the following but it did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('input').one('focus', function() {
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $('input[id='.id.']').popover({'trigger':'focus''});
  });                                                                                                                                           
</script>
```

am trying to avoid having separate events for every input field.

here is the HTML that i am using to manipulate

```
     <input type="email" 
            name="email"
            id="email"
            data-title="E-Mail Address"
            data-content="E-Mail address"
            data-alignment="right"/>
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').one('focus', function() {
      $(this).popover({'trigger':'focus''});
    });
</script>
```

I haven't test it, anyway.

Comment: This is working but for some strange reason it is not firing every time I tab to a new input field.  If I tab out and then back in it does show the popover.  It is though events are being missed.

Comment: @UxBoD: Well, I think that's either a jQuery or Bootstrap issue.

Comment: Darn :( thought it may have been me :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you provide html also. but based upon what you have given,
this is possiible explanation

If input is ID then the following should work. otherwise it will not
you need to give proper selector.

for IDs you append a "#"

and for class names you append a "."

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#email').on('focus', function() {
var id=$(this).attr('id');
$("#"+id).popover({'trigger':'focus''});
 });                                                                                                                                           
 </script>
```

Comment: That does not work. The HTML I am using is simply <input type="email" name="email" id="email" data-title="E-Mail Address" data-content="E-Mail address" data-alignment="right"/>. I did add the following after setting the var: alert("ID:"+id) ... and that showed the correct ID from the input field.